# How to split an array into two after find a specific index in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that start with a specific index, always will be 43 the first index, after that I have info and I would like to split it into 2 after find the value `products` but not always the value `products` will be the index 64 it will be different everytime.

So I tried this to find the index where the value products is

```
$index = array_search('products', $data);
```

This way I can find the index where I would like to split the array in 2, but I have no idea how, I tried with `array_chunk` but I couldn't make it work

This is my original array:

```
Array
(
    [43] => 1234
    [44] => 001
    [45] => 100
    [46] => 0
    [47] => 0
    [48] => 2
    [49] => 
    [50] => 1234
    [51] => 001
    [52] => 100
    [53] => 0
    [54] => 0
    [55] => 2
    [56] => 
    [57] => 
    [58] => 
    [59] => 
    [60] => 
    [61] => 0
    [62] => 1
    [63] => 
    [64] => products
    [65] => 1234
    [66] => 001
    [67] => 100
    [68] => 0
    [69] => 0
    [70] => 2
    [71] => 
    [72] => 1234
    [73] => 001
    [74] => 100
    [75] => 0
    [76] => 0
    [77] => 2
    [78] => 
    [79] => 
    [80] => 
    [81] => 
    [82] => 
    [83] => 0
    [84] => 1
)
```

And I would like something like this:

```
Array
(
    [43] => 1234
    [44] => 001
    [45] => 100
    [46] => 0
    [47] => 0
    [48] => 2
    [49] => 
    [50] => 1234
    [51] => 001
    [52] => 100
    [53] => 0
    [54] => 0
    [55] => 2
    [56] => 
    [57] => 
    [58] => 
    [59] => 
    [60] => 
    [61] => 0
    [62] => 1
    [63] =>
)

Array
( 
    [65] => 1234
    [66] => 001
    [67] => 100
    [68] => 0
    [69] => 0
    [70] => 2
    [71] => 
    [72] => 1234
    [73] => 001
    [74] => 100
    [75] => 0
    [76] => 0
    [77] => 2
    [78] => 
    [79] => 
    [80] => 
    [81] => 
    [82] => 
    [83] => 0
    [84] => 1
)
```

Also without the index of the value `products`, do you have some idea what function can I use to achieve this or another way to do it? I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: have you tried array_slice?

Comment: Just to get the index where is the value `products`

Comment: @Chris I think I found the solution with your comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost, [`array_chunk()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) makes multiple pieces instead you want to *slice* the array in two pieces by a given key, this can be done with [`array_slice()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$split = array_search('products', $data);

print_r(array_slice($data, 0, $split))   // first part
print_r(array_slice($data, $split + 1)); // second part
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: FYI: this will remove 'products' from the final result. If you just want to split into two arrays at a certain index, use `$split` instead of `$split + 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
// an array
$array = array(1, 2, 3, "products", 4, 5);

// $offset = 3
$offset = array_search("products", $array);

// array(4,5)
$last_batch = array_slice($array, ($offset + 1));

// array(1,2,3)
$first_batch = array_slice($array, 0, $offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps :)

```
$Array = array (10, 20, 30, 40);
$count = 0;
foreach($Array as $my_array)
{
 if($my_array == "products")
 {
   count++
   array_chunk($Array, count);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.